# Sync Quote Automatically on record creation

Tags: apex, trigger, class, quote

I am trying to get our quote system to automatically sync a quote on creation if it meets certain criteria. (Status, and a couple of custom fields.)  I have done some research and found a few places that offer solutions but either they are beyond my scope of knowledge or they don't work.  Does anyone have any suggestion on how to facilitate Auto-syncing quotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work with an after insert trigger on the quote object. You check in the trigger if the quote meets your criteria and you also have the opportunity id which you can use to follow this method to get it synced
http://hisrinu.wordpress.com/2012/03/28/syncing-quotes-using-apex-5/

Comment: I was able to take that little snippet and place it within the controller itself.  Once the Quote was created, it passed on the ID to the opportunity field and updated it.  The quote syncs perfectly through the VF page now.  Thank you very much!